# How to turn off headers with KOMA-Script Book

Tags: header-footer, lyx, koma-script

I'm using the KOMA-Script Book class to create a book in LyX. I don't want to have any headers in my book, but they're active by default. Is there anything I can do to turn them off?

Thank you for any help you may provide!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the LyX example files that use KOMA-Script Book. For example, try File > Open, click on "Examples" button, click on the "thesis" folder and open thesis.lyx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are four predefined page styles that can be used with KOMA-Script class without loading an additional package for header and footer.

You can use `\pagestyle{plain}` to get the page number in footer but an empty header.

- **`empty`**: header and footer are empty
- **`headings`**: page number in footer, headings will be set by chapters, sections etc.
- **`myheadings`**: page number in footer, headings have to be set by the user
- **`plain`**: page number in footer, header is empty

The default page style of `scrbook` is `headings`. So the chapter will be in header on even pages and the sections on odd pages.

It seems that you want to use page style `plain`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\pagestyle{plain}    
\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `\pagestyle{myheadings}`. This pagestyle allows to set own header entries using `\markboth` or `\markright`. These entries will then not be changed by new chapters or sections.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument% empty header
\markboth
  {My header entry on even pages}
  {My header entry on odd pages}
\blinddocument% header with own entries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that in LyX, the page style can be set inside Document properties > Page format. `\markboth` can be entered by hand in the preamble tab.

Comment: Thank you, esdd. It seems to work perfectly. I'm very thankful for your reply! :)