# Remove Running Headers Temporarily: scrbook, Koma Class

Tags: header-footer, scrbook

SCRBook, Koma-class.
I need to remove running headers (primarily the reference to subsections, since there aren't any) in the introduction.

Is there a way to turn the headers off, and then back on? 
Perhaps a \pagestyle{empty} environment for the three page introduction? Ideally I'd be able to keep the page numbers, though this is not crucial.

I looked at this question, but the answer deals with removing headers globally: [How to turn off headers with KOMA-Script Book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307413/how-to-turn-off-headers-with-koma-script-book)

MWE:  (it's too long, unfortunately, so I posted it here:

https://pastebin.com/CZT6tyEr

Comment: Please add the code of a MWE (= **minimal** working example) to your question. You can use package `lipsum` or package `blindtext` for dummy text.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following helps:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
%
\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Using plain style}
\Blindtext[10]
\clearpage\pagestyle{headings}% maybe you have to replace "headings" by the name of your page style
% 
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
%
\begingroup\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Using plain style}
\Blindtext[10]
\clearpage\endgroup
% 
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: This removed the headers globally. I want to be able to turn them back on after the introduction. I added a MWE just before you posted.

Comment: Not in my example. First pages of new chapters use page style `plain` by default. But the following pages in the third chapter use page style `headings` again. Maybe your document uses a different style or a package? But then you have to add an MWE to your question.

Comment: If your document does not use page style `headings`, you have to use the name of your page style after the second `\clearpage` in my first example. Maybe you have to redeclare `plain` style too to get your desired result. It is not recommended to use `titlesec` and `titleps` with a KOMA-Script class. But  in your  linked code you have to add `\renewpagestyle{plain}{``\setheadrule{0.009pt}``\sethead[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}``}` to get a `plain` style with the pagenumber in header.

Comment: The intro still references non-existent section numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there is a simple fix. 
To turn off a specialized page style, use the command:

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Then, to turn on the custom page style, use the command:

```
\pagestyle{custom} %% where *custom* is the name of the page style used in the rest of the document.
```